# Error in reseting email using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium I wanted to test a web design where a user can reset the password. 
Given the code below:

```
@Test
    public void AdminForgot(){
        driver.get("http://phptravels.net/admin");
        WebElement forgotPassword = driver.findElement(By.id("link-forgot"));
                    forgotPassword.click();
        WebElement resetEmail = driver.findElement(By.name("email"));
                    resetEmail.clear();
                    resetEmail.sendKeys("");
        WebElement resetPassword = driver.findElement(By.id("btn-forgot"));
                    resetPassword.click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

Whenever I try to test it using testNG I always get an error like this:
`org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Unexpected modal dialog(text: Please Enter Email Address): Please Enter Email Address`

Does anyone here know how to find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

@newbie

There are a few things you that needs attention

1. you're passing an empty string as an argument to `sendkeys("")` which is showing a pop-up & that needs to be handled.If you intent to pass an empty string then include the line below after `Sendkeys()`

`driver.switchto().alert().accept()`

2. If you don't want to pass an empty string, then you don't need to include it.